# The multi-part identifier "T_SBIL_AD_Data.lab_displayName" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have created new table in my database called T_AD_Data, when I am trying to join the table to V_ALL. getting error.

```
SELECT case V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages when 0

then V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages + (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages + ((V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2) - (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages)))

else

V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages

end as PrintedPages,V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages as BWPages,V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages as ColorPages,

case V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages when 0 then

V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages + ((V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2) - (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages))

else V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages

end as BlankPages,V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages as SimplexPages,


V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2 as DuplexPages,


V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages as TotalSheets,V_All.JOB_lab_NTDomainName, V_All.Lab_GroupName, V_All.JOB_lab_NTUserName, V_All.Lab_NTFullUserName, V_All.PRINTER_lab_Location, V_All.JOB_lab_DocumentName, V_All.JOB_qty_Size, V_All.JOB_qty_Copies, V_All.JOB_date_Submitted, T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName, T_AD_Data.lab_department, T_AD_Data.lab_physicalDeliveryOfficeName FROM V_ALL JOIN T_AD_Data AD_Data ON V_ALL.JOB_lab_NTUserName=T_AD_Data.lab_displayName;
```

Results:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "T_AD_Data.lab_displayName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "T_AD_Data.lab_department" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "T_AD_Data.lab_" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Prefix `T_AD_Data` doesn't exist anywhere.  You're attempting to use it in your join, but have no table named or aliased as such anywhere else in your `FROM` clause.  Same goes for the last three fields of your `SELECT`.

It looks like either `T_SBIL_AD_Data` should be aliased as `T_AD_Data` (instead of `SBIL_AD_Data)`, or you are you missing an entire table / view from your `FROM` clause.

EDIT: Using additional info from your comment, the answer is there is a table `T_AD_Data` that has columns you are referencing in both your `SELECT` and `JOIN` but the table is not anywhere in the `FROM` clause.

What you need is for your FROM clause to be something like this...

```
FROM 
    V_ALL 
    <SOME SORTA> JOIN T_AD_Data ON V_ALL.<Some_Field_In_V_All> = T_AD_Data.<Some_Field_In_T_AD_Data>
    JOIN T_SBIL_AD_Data SBIL_AD_Data ON V_ALL.JOB_lab_NTUserName = T_AD_Data.lab_displayName
```

To be clear, `<SOME SORTA>` is a placeholder for whatever type of JOIN makes the most sense based on your actual data and the desired result (i.e. `LEFT OUTER`, `INNER`, etc.).

Also `V_ALL.<Some_Field_In_V_All>` and `T_AD_Data.<Some_Field_In_T_AD_Data>` are pseudocode placeholders for actual fields from each of those respective tables.  Based on the field names you provided, maybe `V_All.Lab_NTFullUserName` and `T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName`, but that's not much more than a guess.

Comment: Hi Joe,its my mistake, I am fresher to sql, some using google I created query. I am using T_AD_Data as a table name. If you don't mind Can you please correct the query and send me.

Comment: If T_AD_Data is another table, you'd need to put it in your JOIN.  Without a lot more detail on the schema and knowledge of the data, I don't know what fields to match up for that missing JOIN.  Even if you create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for it, you'd have to tell us what fields link to what other fields in other tables.

Comment: Table: V_ALL, and these are columns V_All.JOB_lab_NTDomainName, V_All.Lab_GroupName, V_All.JOB_lab_NTUserName, V_All.Lab_NTFullUserName, V_All.PRINTER_lab_Location, V_All.JOB_lab_DocumentName, V_All.JOB_qty_Size, V_All.JOB_qty_Copies, V_All.JOB_date_Submitted,
Table2: T_AD_Data and these are columns T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName, T_SBIL_AD_Data.lab_department, T_AD_Data.lab_ physicalDeliveryOfficeName.     Please ignore T_SBIL_AD_Data. The sum query is working fine. when I join the 2nd table I am getting error.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for post, I am getting the table names in result but not data in the tables.